# OpenGL SwapBuffers error 1282

Tags: opengl, freeglut

I recently bought a GTX 750 ti and i installed the 353.38 nvidia drivers with success. When I create an OpenGL 3.3 context and if I call `glutSwapBuffers` I get a 1282 error. 
Here are the sources:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GL\freeglut.h"


void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSwapBuffers();

    std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl; //<= 1282
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int OpenGLVersion[2];

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("GL 3.3 Test");

    glewExperimental=TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK)
        return 1;

    while (glGetError()) { }

    cout << "OpenGL version = " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;

    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[0]);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &OpenGLVersion[1]);
    cout << "OpenGL major version = " <<OpenGLVersion[0] << endl;
    cout << "OpenGL minor version = " <<OpenGLVersion[1] << endl;

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I thing this is a driver's bug. Can someone help me?

Comment: Nothing obvious wrong in your program. Be advised that the `…SwapBuffers` function is actually not part of the OpenGL API, but belongs to the graphics system GL support API (wgl, GLX, and so on). I suggest you litter your program with glGetError calls (remember to loop it until `==GL_NO_ERROR` every time) so see where exactly the error condition is flaged.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i already filled all the code with a loop of glGetError and I get that error only after swapping the buffers.

Comment: I think you have 1282, because OpenGL did not inited correct. For Windows you can call wglGetCurrentContext in disply to get current OpenGL context. If it is NULL, problem is in init function.

Comment: I tried but the context is not NULL. I created a more complex program that draw a 3d cube with shaders. It is like if depth test is not enabled. I tried with GLFW3 instead of freeglut and i get the same problem.

Comment: @KrounNouns: I don't see how this would result in the behaviour you are getting, but `GLUT_CORE_PROFILE` is not the correct value for `glutInitContextFlags()`. The corrct function is `glutInitContextProfile`. However, freeglut defines the context flags`GLUT_DEBUG` as 1, as well as a profile flag `GLUT_CORE_PROFILE` - so you actually create a debug context instead of a core profile context with this code. It still should work in both cases, though. But what I wanted to recommend you is explicitely creating a debug context and registering a debug callback to get more info on the error...

Comment: Hi derhass. I followed this guide to create a debug context : [link](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2013/02/17/debugging-opengl-part-2-using-gldebugmessagecallback/) but "glDebugMessageCallback" is not available and this is strange.

Comment: EDIT: Oh "glDebugMessageCallback" must go after context creation and now works. When I open the program i get the console spammed by this : "Function glVertex2f is deprecated and not avaiable in preview contexts".... but I don't have glVertex2f() in my code...

Comment: @KrounNouns: It's a long shot but you may try dumping the current strack backtrace from the debug message callback. On Linux with glibc this is pretty straightforward (see `man backtrace`). On Windows though… I've got a portable backtrace library in my projects TODO list, but nothing workable I could give you right now.

Comment: @KrounNouns: Hmm, that's very weird indeed. I don't see how the GL could complain about `glVertex2f()` calls when running this code, unless you run it under some GL interceptor which is introducing new calls under the hood. Trying to get the backtrace as @datenwolf suggested seems like a very good idea. But besides trying to do that in your program, you can also simply run it in a debugger and set a break point somewhere in your debug callback.

Comment: I'm very confused... I did a clean installation of nvidia drivers and I get same problem. The spam of that messages (~450 call of debugCallback) is not infinity. I get also Push/PopMatrix MatrixMode Push/PopAttrib errors.

Comment: Omg... After 6 hours of debugging and raging I finally discovered the problem. Recently I have installed MSI Afterburner and RivaTunerStatisticServer. These program draw on screen of any application/games some statistics like FPS, CPU/GPU temperatures, eccetera. When I open my program these program try to draw something in the window. I fixed the problem closing these program when I'm developing. Thanks to all for the support :)